# Removing public/index.php?

Tags: codeigniter-2, bonfire

How do we remove the `public/index.php` from ci-bonfire 0.7 ?

I see there are instructions to remove the root `index.php` but I am unable to remove the root `public/index.php` and there are no instructions related to it.

I have tried instructions in http://cibonfire.com/docs/bonfire/removing_index without any success. I keep getting the 404 when I go to

```
http://localhost/Bonfire-0.7/index.php
```

but

`http://localhost/Bonfire-0.7/public/index.php`

works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Open directory `application/config/config.php` and do the following:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: I am still not getting through. The site still needs to be accessed as `http://localhost/Bonfire-0.7/public/index.php/login` instead of `http://localhost/Bonfire-0.7/index.php/login` or `http://localhost/Bonfire-0.7/login`

Comment: Basically, I am unable to remove the `public` from the url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XAMPP + bonfire v0.7,  I've installed it under a subdirectory called "ci-bonfire", this is my solution.

**To remove index.php in URL**

Step 1: Goto **ci-bonfire/application/config/config.php**, remove "index.php" from index-page config.

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Step 2: Change **1.htaccess** in *ci-bonfire/public/* to **.htaccess**
update line #158, change to your subdirectory name

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /ci-bonfire
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^bonfire/codeigniter.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and further down to line #182, prepend "public" to "index.php"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**To remove public/index.php in URL**

Step 1: Goto **ci-bonfire/application/config/config.php**, remove "index.php" from index-page config.

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Step 2: Rename (for backup purpose) or remove **index.php** and **.htaccess** in your subdirectory, *ci-bonfire*

Step 3: Then refer to "Reverting To Traditional Structure" in this [cibonfire's documentation](http://cibonfire.com/docs/developer/site_structure).  Move all files from *public* folder up 1 level to your subdirectory.

Step 4: Update **index.php** as the following

```
$path = ".";
```

Hope it helps, it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

**To remove public/index.php in Remote WebServer (in production)**

**Step 1:** Goto application/config/config.php, remove "index.php" from index-page config.

> $config['index_page'] = ""; (line 35)

**Step 2:** Remove index.php and .htaccess in your / (root)

**Step 3:** Move all files from /public folder to / (root).

**Step 4:** Update the new index.php in / as the following

> $path = "."; (line 74)

It's all! Be happy!

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had this error in CodeIgniter the installation in the server works such the next example:

> SERVER_IP/public/index.php/controller/method

But I need

> SERVER_IP/controller/method

My Solution is very very simple, my project is in the root directory then I go to the root directory and I have to create a .htaccess file configuration. like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   //Setting de base URL. 
   RewriteBase /public
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   //Setting the pattern to match 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

The final result is:

> Request: SERVER_IP/login => SERVER_IP/public/index.php/login
>
> Request: SERVER_IP/login/doLogin => SERVER_IP/public/index.php/login/doLogin
>
> Request: SERVER_IP/login/logout?noredirect=1 => SERVER_IP/public/index.php/login/logout?noredirect=1

Good Luck...

Answer (score -1):

Try:

IR Carpeta  : public/
Go folder public/

rename the public/ 1.htaccess to .htaccess

http://cibonfire.com/docs/developer/removing_index

Edit the .htaccess file and to add a RewriteBase option pointing to the folder that you're using around line 151 to 165 replace.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public
```